# How to select first data charted in SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the next query to create a view, but I need to select the fist data charted. The Database contains a large number of data with the attributeID = 47772, and also has a colummn with the charTime. My idea is to order the table by chartime and then select the fist one. The code I have is the next:

```
SET @TINGRESO= 
(
    select   PtAssessment.terseForm 
    FROM     PtAssessment  
    WHERE    ( attributeId =47772 AND  PtAssessment.encounterId = @encounterIdAUX) AND (ptAssessmentId =
             (
                 SELECT    TOP 1 (ptAssessmentId) 
                 FROM      PtAssessment
                 WHERE     ( attributeId =47772 AND    (PtAssessment.encounterId = @encounterIdAUX ))
             ) 
)
```

BUt with this code I can not select the fist data charted. If I add "order by" I get an error:
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the `top 1`

```
    SET @TINGRESO= 
(
    select  top 1 PtAssessment.terseForm 
    FROM     PtAssessment  
    WHERE    ( attributeId =47772 AND  PtAssessment.encounterId = @encounterIdAUX) AND (ptAssessmentId =
             (
                 SELECT    TOP 1 (ptAssessmentId) 
                 FROM      PtAssessment
                 WHERE     ( attributeId =47772 AND    (PtAssessment.encounterId = @encounterIdAUX ))
             ) 
)
```

Comment: I need to order by chartTime. I can not use directly TOP 1 because the first row is not the first charted data

Answer (score 1):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select @TINGRESO = p.terseForm 
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.attributeid order by chartime desc) as seqnum
      from ptassessment p
      where p.attributeId = 47772 and p.encounterId = @encounterIdAUX
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

This assumes that `chartime` is in a reasonable format for ordering.  In general, you should store dates and times using native types.

Comment: If I use the sequence you are suggesting I get the next error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. Notice that I'm defining the pointer @TINGRESO with SET clause

Comment: @user3795094 . . . This version has no `set` clause.  Notice that it is assigning a value using `select`.  I cannot see how this query would generate that error, given that the only subquery is in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Did you  try

```
select @TINGRESO =  PtAssessment.terseForm 
    FROM     PtAssessment  
    WHERE    ( attributeId =47772 AND  PtAssessment.encounterId = @encounterIdAUX) AND (ptAssessmentId =
             (
                 SELECT    TOP 1 (ptAssessmentId) 
                 FROM      PtAssessment
                 WHERE     ( attributeId =47772 AND    (PtAssessment.encounterId = @encounterIdAUX ))
             ) 
ORDER BY [CONDITION]
```

Comment: Yes, but I got the next error: 
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: I feel there is simpler solution for that. Could you post  table structure and desired result

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the next query that worked for me:

```
SET @TINGRESO= 
(
SELECT 
    p.terseForm
FROM
    PtAssessment p
    WHERE  
    p.attributeId =47772 
    AND  p.encounterId = @encounterIdAUX
    AND  p.ChartTime=
        (
            SELECT  
                MIN(a.ChartTime)
            FROM    
                PtAssessment a
                    WHERE   
                a.attributeId =47772
                AND a.encounterId = @encounterIdAUX
            )
)
```